# Movie where a painting comes alive in a young man's dream

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a movie about a painting that comes alive in a young man's dream while he stays at his uncle's house.

It's based in the Victorian era, I believe. They were still getting around with horse drawn wagons. The man sleeps with the lady in the painting in his dream then in the end of the movie he sees the painting for sale years later in a store and tries to buy it but the lady in the painting buys it before he has a chance to when he returns to buy it. I saw it on HBO or Showtime, I think in the early 90's. It had a Shakespeare feel to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you remember an episode of [Série rose](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0877465/), also known as [Softly from Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softly_from_Paris) in English. It was a French series that depicted famous old erotic stories.

[image: Image from the series]

The episode was called "Hercule aux pieds d'Omphale" and was an adaption of [Théophile Gautiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9ophile_Gautier) story "Omphale" from his book "[One of Cleopatra's Nights and Other Fantastic Romances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_of_Cleopatra%27s_Nights_and_Other_Fantastic_Romances)" that was published in 1882.

The story is told from the viewpoint of Théophile himself that spent a few weeks with his uncle, the owner of an old rococo-style house. The walls of his room were covered with a tapestry representing a mythological scene: Hercules sitting at the feet of Queen Omphale. Both Hercules and Omphale was painted to resemble the uncle and his wife Julie.

At night Théophile dreams that the queen leaves the tapestry and that they make love. It is hinted that these dreams really are Julie seducing him while he sleeps, but it is unresolved. Hercules/The uncle gets suspicious about this though and has the tapestry removed.

Years late Théophile finds the tapestry in a antique store, and he thinks the queen winks at him. He tries to buy it, but before he has returned with money the tapestry has been sold.

Comment: Thank you! I have wondered about that for years and looked on Google forever and never figured it out! I appreciate your help. Im going to watch it as an adult and see if I remeber it the way I believed

Comment: Do you know where to watch in in English or with subtitles? I searched Hugh and low

Comment: @Alex No idea i am afraid. It is a bit old and was never very popular. I think you just have to keep your eyes open and hope for the best.